# how to restrict the user to create an object for class but allow to access methods in that class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Project :**BAL**

```
class A
{   
  a()
   {}
}
```

Project :**Usage**

```
Test
{
     A a=new A()---->I should get an error here
}
```

here i'm giving an access to the user. BAL is a class library where i'm going to provide to all

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You want to prevent users from creating instances altogether?  Or just from some layers.  How do you expect your methods to be accessed if instances of the class cannot be created?

Comment: Not clear what else you are looking for - your sample as shown prevents external callers to construct your object already...

Answer (score 1):

Make you constructor private

```
class A
{
    private A() {}
}
```

Comment: Correct - private constructor. you can create the instance internally if you wish and also have it as a singleton pattern (if you wanted) but this definitely does not allow the other parts of the system to create an instance of this object but still access methods and properties.